# What is name of the timer/counter overflow interrupt in stm32

Tags: timer, stm32, stm32f4, stm32ldiscovery

I am using timer in input capture mode in STM32 micro with keil compiler, and I want to trigger an interrupt whenever counter register of the dedicated timer overflows.

Could anyone please tell me how i can do that? what is the name of this interrupt?

Note: I am using hal functions.

Comment: Read the documentation.

Comment: http://www.keil.com/download/docs/352.asp There is an example of using the external interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the (exact) controller type you are using on the STM homepage (you can start from here:
https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus.html

On the product page for your controller, you'll find a useful list of PDFs under "Resources", especially

- the **Reference Manual** (find the register descriptions in the TIM description of the timer you use)
- a list of **Application Notes**, which are relevant for all STM32 families, especially

  - **AN4776**
    General-purpose timer cookbook for STM32 microcontrollers
    https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00236305-generalpurpose-timer-cookbook-for-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf
    and
  - **AN4013**
    STM32 cross-series timer overview
    https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00042534-stm32-crossseries-timer-overview-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Looking for the correct library functions, you can use STM32CubeMX to configure the timers in a GUI and have the correct driver codes generated for you.

Good luck!